# How will I cache response of the below GraphQL schema? I'm using apollo client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo client for search functionality in my react app. Every time user enters/changes the text in the input, a GraphQL API is to be hit. I want to cache responses to avoid multiple requests of the same query. The query has two variables. One is the input string, and another is a simple filter object which consists of the selected filter.

This is how the request looks like

```
query lookup(
  $input: String!,
  $filterObj: FilterObj
) {
    description
    type
    identifier {
      symbol
  }  
}
```

The response looks like this.

```
{
    "lookup": [
        {
            "description": "Some description",
            "type": "type1",
            "identifier": {
                "symbol": "XYZ",
                "__typename": "Identifier"
            },
            "__typename": "SearchResult"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above response, description and type are non unique, symbol value is unique. How can I cache response to avoid hitting the API multiple times with the same variables?